# Why is Angular/AngularFirestore creating new objects instead of treating as immutable?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating tables of input boxes from Firebase stored JSON objects called `Page`. `Page` is a JSON object that represents a table with rows and cells and cell elements within the cells. I load and create the Angular components from the Page JSON object representing the table, like this:

```html
<table app-page class="page"*ngFor="let page of pages | async" [page]="page" border="5" [attr.height]="page.pheight" [attr.width]="page.pwidth" align="center" valign="top"></table>
```

Everytime a value in an input box on a page changes, I call a method from the input box component `onBlur`, to save that page in the Firestore, like this:

```js
inputBlur(e: Event) {
  this.cellel.value = this.inputEl.nativeElement.value.trim();
  var page = this.scService.getCurrPageComp().page;
  console.log("page =" + page);
  this.afs.collection('pages').doc(page.$key).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(page)));
}
```

The problem is that after this.afs stores the updated Page object. The entire tree `let page of pages | async` comes back as if they are new objects and it rebuilds the page as if it were new. I don't want it to do anything with the views. I just want it to store the updated `Page` and not reload it as if it were a new object `Page`.

Here is a Stackblitz showing the situation:

https://ang-change-detect-1.stackblitz.io

Comment: You should also look into ngFor's trackBy feature. You'd really want to use that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked at your code on stackblitz, the problem is because of line 28 in `cxforms.component.ts`, specifically, this part: `this.pages = this.pagesCollection.snapshotChanges()`

`snapshotChanges()` is a **listener**, whenever that portion of the database changes (*in this case the 'pages' table, which changes when you update a value*) then it will push a fresh copy of the data to your client - thereby refreshing your table. It sounds like you want to make a one-time query to Firestore to get the page/table data, and not listen for changes or updated data.

Check out [this page of the Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), which shows you how to make a simple (*one time*) query for data using `.get()`... check out the 2nd to last example on the page, titled "Get all documents in a collection"... copied below for your reference:

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```